# What is the unit for the tx.gasprice?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, gas-price, solidity-0.5.x

Is it a wei, kwei, mwei, gwei, ... Something else?

[The API](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/units-and-global-variables.html) doesn't say much.

Comment: wei (typing more to meet minimum length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit is wei.

Wei is the lowest possible denomination that can be handled by Solidity. Because of this, various values can be calculated (but not necessarily the other way around), such as ether, `tx.gasprice`, and even ERC20 tokens with arbitrary `decimals`.

Comment: ERC20 tokens do not use decimals, there is no floating point system in solidity https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/how-can-i-represent-decimal-values-in-solidity/2990