# Compiling a Smart Contract

Tags: remix, dapps

I can't compile my smart contract that I'm trying to deploy:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract DepositContract {
    // The amount of time (in hours) that the contract will run for
    const uint256 DURATION_HOURS = 24;
    // The payout rate (in percentage per hour)
    const uint256 PAYOUT_RATE = 4.16666666667;

    // Mapping from user address to their deposit balance
    mapping(address => uint256) public deposits;

    // The total amount of deposits in the contract
    uint256 public totalDeposits;

    // The start time of the contract (in seconds)
    uint256 public startTime;

    // The end time of the contract (in seconds)
    uint256 public endTime;

    // Flag to indicate whether the contract is active
    bool public isActive;

    constructor() public {
        // Set the start and end times of the contract
        startTime = now;
        endTime = startTime + DURATION * 3600;
        // Set the contract to be active
        isActive = true;
    }

    // Function to deposit FTM into the contract
    function deposit() public payable {
        // Check that the contract is still active
        require(isActive, "The contract is no longer active.");
        // Check that the deposit is not zero
        require(msg.value > 0, "Deposit
```

It keeps giving me this error:

```
    contracts/DepositContract.sol:6:11: ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'uint256'
    const uint256 DURATION_HOURS = 24;
    ^-----^
```

Comment: const is not solidity, try constant instead and after the type, like this: `uint256 constant DURATION = 24;`

Comment: Thank you, I corrected it but now it's giving me this error: contracts/DepositContract.sol:38:32: ParserError: Expected string end-quote.
require(msg.value > 0, "Deposit
^------^

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an end quote, parenthesis, and semicolon in your final require statement along with a few other syntax issues. You will also need a closing bracket to close out the deposit() function, along with a second closing bracket to close out your contract. Try this:

```
// Function to deposit FTM into the contract
    function deposit() public payable {
        // Check that the contract is still active
        require(isActive, "The contract is no longer active.");
        // Check that the deposit is not zero
        require(msg.value > 0, "Deposit");
        }
    }
```

You also declare a constant DURATION_HOURS but then go on to use an undeclared variable DURATION in your constructor. I assume they are meant to be the same, so in your constructor, try this:

```
endTime = startTime + DURATION_HOURS * 3600;
```

Lastly solidity does not support fixed point numbers so your declaration of:

```
uint256 constant PAYOUT_RATE = 4.16666666667;
```

will need to change to:

```
uint256 constant PAYOUT_RATE = 416666666667;
```

For more information please refer to this
[How can I represent decimal values in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/how-can-i-represent-decimal-values-in-solidity)

Solidity by Example may be helpful when running into syntax problems in the future:
https://solidity-by-example.org/